# Unable to de-rank people with Roblox groups api, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, roblox

Due to issues, we need to mass de-rank a lot of people, but when attempting to make a request through Roblox's group api, it returns 401 (unauthorized request)

I'm pretty sure the token is valid, and the bot does have permission to derank them. The code is below.

```
const token = "TOKEN WOULD GO HERE BUT NOT SHOWN"
const axios = require('axios')
const noblox = require('noblox.js')
const rolesetID = 36926359
const groupId = 5598688
const url = `https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/5598688/roles/${rolesetID}/users?limit=100`
let userCount = 0

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    axios.get(`${url}`)
    .then(async function (response) {
        response.data.data.forEach(async data => {
          if(data.username == 'lickty123') {
          } else {
            let url = `https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/5598688/users/${data.userId}`
            await axios.patch(url, { body: { roleId: 36926437,Cookie: ".ROBLOSECURITY=" + token} })
            .then(async (res) => {
                console.log(`${data.userID} has been demoted!`)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
            })
        }
      });
      // userCount = userCount + 100
     // console.log(`${userCount} people have been demoted`)
    })
    wait(1)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put the Cookie field in headers, not body
you also have to include your x-csrf-token in headers, which can be achieved with noblox via `noblox.getGeneralToken()`